# Recommended dhcpd Web Interfaces?

Tags: graphical-user-interface, dhcp-server

Can anyone recommend a solid dhcpd web interface? Google searches turn up all kinds of results, including projects that haven't been updated since 2002. I'm looking for something that is a little more maintained and widely deployed.

Answer (score 1):

[Webmin](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/DHCPServer) can manage ISC dhcpd installations. You should check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [PHPDHCPAdmin](http://phpdhcpadmin.sourceforge.net/)?

I agree that the currently available projects leave something to be desired. This is at least a little quicker then editing the config via command-line when I want to modify my giant collection of client's static IP assignments.